# Forward email items as attachment one by one by excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation

I have many email items.

I put them in my excel from outlook, know I can reply all of them by excel vbn, but i can't forward as attachment to department. by excel vbn

I need code  to help me to do it

I am trying but I don't have enough information

Comment: What code have you tried so far? SO is for dev questions, not for requesting a ready made code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `MailItem` instance and then attach the original item as an attachment:

```
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objMsg
        .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
        .Subject = "SPAM"
        .To = "spam@host.co.uk"
        .Send
    End With
```

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

You my find the [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new message using `Application.CreateItem(0)`, then add the messages you want to be forwarded as attachments by passing them to `MailItem.Attachments.Add`.

Comment: I need full code

Comment: It is pretty hard to provide any code since you never posted any code that you want changed.